# Facebook share on a different domain than your app configuration?

Tags: facebook, share

This is the code for the share button:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: 'http://cheese.com/',
});
```

I have multiple domains reusing one app id. We did some workarounds for logging in etc. But at least I hoped the share button would just work. But this gives me a classic:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

The error makes sense: I try to share something on another domain. But why is there this limitation in the first place? Is there a workaround?

Note that the send link dialog doesn't give any problems:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    link: 'http://cheese.com/',
});
```

What's so different between `share` and `send`?

What would be a workaround when using multiple domain names for a single app?

Comment: This is not about the method used in `FB.ui`, this is about initialization of the JS SDK. You are supposed to mainly use one domain with your app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using the old `sharer.php` way in a new window.

```
window.open( 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://poules.com', 
    'fbShareWindow',       
    'toolbar=no,
     location=no,
     status=no,
     menubar=no,
     scrollbars=yes,
     resizable=yes,
     width=600,
     height=400');
```

Comment: It would seem this is the only way to do it. Even if you set up 2 separate applications in Facebook, it still checks the url you are trying to share is the same as the current url of the site you are on (or a subdomain), if it's not you get an error.

Answer (score 2):

`Method share:` This is used for sharing domains or subdomains on Facebook publicly or as you specify in a post. It is affecting app's publicity. (How efficiently people are sharing links/URLs). Usually app's name which reflects while sharing makes huge impact.

`Method send:` This is used for sending private messages on Facebook. It is not much affecting app's publicity.

I think this is kept like this because,

Any content on page which could have different links than a domain registered on Facebook App. And also it is gonna sent as private message only which not bothers to Facebook much. But if it used as share then it should have similar domain or subdomain because it is in turn affecting Facebook's reputation. (Keep in mind spammers.)

So I feel, if domains are different then create different Facebook app.